# pasar URL metodo encriptado sin que se corte PHP

Tags: php, url

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

Estoy realizando un proyecto, el cual me trae por URL GET una palabra encriptada que contiene el símbolo / y el navegador lo corta ya que este entiende que debe cortar en esa linea

Ejemplo:

```
1atCXYEBTttPaGtVGcFtzKwnLyylko1gpmSm1/SM=
```

Al pasar esta encriptacion por URL al llegar a la barra divisoria (  /  ) el navegador no agrega los caracteres faltantes que son SM= y el proyecto me comienza a mostrar FATAL ERROR.

Como podría solucionar este tema, ya que si o si debo pasar por GET

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la siguiente función para codificar la url:

```php
urlencode("1atCXYEBTttPaGtVGcFtzKwnLyylko1gpmSm1/SM=");
```